# How to get text on a batch with wide type of receipt with Tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have to OCR a batch receipt / invoice (some scanned, some not) with a wide variation of angle and quality and language (French, English, and Spanish)
The script I do can handle I think like 30% of my batch perfectly, but I have some receipt where I'm hard to get result from, like the example provided.

I'm using Python and pytesseract, I have the image on disk so pytesseract should not make any preprocessing.

This is a mini example of code I used to detect the angle, get a bird's-eye view of the receipt and extract the text with pytesseract.

```py
    transform_ok = True

    orig_img = Image.open(my_file)
    # convert from RGB (PIL) to BGR (CV2)
    orig = cv2.cvtColor(asarray(orig_img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    image = orig.copy()
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
    ratio = orig.shape[1] / float(image.shape[1])

    # apply image transformation, color -> gray -> add a little blur -> edged focus
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Get rid of noise with Gaussian Blur filter
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5,), 0)
    # edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 75, 200)
    edged = imutils.auto_canny(blurred)

    # find and sorted contour for find receipt (bigest edge)
    # cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]
    receiptCnt = None
    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # approximate the contour
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        # if our approximated contour has four points, then we can
        # assume we have found the outline of the receipt
        if len(approx) == 4:
            receiptCnt = approx
            break
    # Receipt contour not found
    if receiptCnt is None:
        print("Could not find receipt outline, "
              "Used raw document")
        # transform fail...
        transform_ok = False
    if transform:
        # top-down bird's-eye view of the receipt
        receipt = four_point_transform(orig, receiptCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
        cv2.imwrite("receipt.jpeg", page)
    else:
        orig_img.save("receipt.jpeg")

    raw_text = pytesseract.image_to_data(
        "receipt.jpeg",
        config=f"--tessdata-dir {tessdata_dir_best} --oem 1 --psm 4",
        lang='script/Latin+fra+eng+spa',
        output_type='dict'
    )
```

Note: Is you can see I also used the for more accuracy [tessdata best](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best)

This is an example of receipt I have.
This one is french, and I can't get any text from it, and the bird view script fail…
[image: Hard receipt]

How can I improve this result ?

I tried [this](https://github.com/ahs8w/unproject_text) but with no effect on this receipt

Any help / clue is welcome!

Comment: You could try color thresholding on the black text from the color input image. Then get rid of the wide black tile cracks that will also get thresholded.

Answer (score 1):

You should use black & white picture. Play around with the size and gray values. It depends on the picture quality a lot:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('receipt.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

print('Original Dimensions : ',img.shape)
 
scale_percent = 100 # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

print('Resized Dimensions : ',resized.shape)

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# 127 between black and white, 255 white 
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 85, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# ocr text
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(blackAndWhiteImage)
print(text)

cv2.imshow('image', blackAndWhiteImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output: not 100%, but you can play around by your own a bit

```
VANIKORO

Contre cia) Paridis
“4 Nantes
Ter : 02 28 23 64 97

mera = Dette Heure Etab
DUPLICATA

x
3000001982180 2E8-TAGBLU a

renise Promotion -20,00%
sur 92,00 soit -18,40

x44% 73,60 EUR #4

1 article
eee Reglenent =”
Carte bleue 73,60 €
Taxe “Wontant. Taux Base HT
TWA 12,27 20,00% 61,33
Co ease temas Wall ag tac baylen ca

° sb. Merch” a varre compréhansion
Vous avez 6té consei11é par
SVLVIE
```